# Prevent simultaneous execution of workflow jobs

Tags: jenkins-workflow

When using a SCM trigger, e. g. every two minutes, how can I prevent a simultaneous execution of my job when there are two commits approximately at the same time?

Comment: As a second to this, what is the expected behavior for simultaneous jobs? If I have a job kick off subsequent build to a previous one, if that previous one is still running while the next build passes it, shouldn't that supersede the previous one? In my setup the previous build stays in its current state while the later one continues on to further stages, even completing.

Answer (score 0):

This is requested in [JENKINS-26860](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26860), which also discusses how the `stage` step can be used to manage concurrency in *certain* cases.